# Is the root function computationally equivalent to function application?

Tags: type-theory, mathematical-foundations, curry-howard

If a function type is representable by [exponentiation](https://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/discrete/types/byType/exponent/index.htm), does it follow that function application is represented by the right inverse, roots? It would seem that roots consume a function's input to return the output, and logarithms consume a function's output to return the input.

\begin{equation}
\sqrt[a] {b^a} = b
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\log_{b} {b^a} = a
\end{equation}

I don't know of any mathematical notation that lets one flip the notation to represent application nicely, so I'll abuse some notation briefly to layout out some identities in a way that feels computationally intuitive to me.

- Exponent: (`<-` or `->`)
- Root (right inverse): (`<-o` or `o->`)
- Logarithm (left inverse): (`o<-` or `->o`)

Given this notation, function application seems to resemble:

`(A -> B) <-o A = B` (when `f: A -> B`, and `a: A`, then `f(A): B`)

Logarithms look like the following, perhaps representing ideas like looking up the index for an array element:

`(A -> B) ->o B = B`

Is this baseless conjecture, or is there research to support this?

Comment: I've found a related question here:
https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17006/what-is-the-logarithm-or-root-operation-in-type-space

Indeed, logarithm types seem to be similar to what I described, but the verdict is still out for root types...

Comment: What you call "this conjecture" is unclear to me. Could you state it explicitly ?

Comment: I don't think that an exponential type is related to the exponential function (except for cardinality issues). What would a "root type" be ?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking in terms of cardinality here. Say I have a function that takes a boolean and returns a triple. There are 9 possible such functions. If I apply one of those functions to a boolean (by taking the square root), then I get a triple. Thus the actual application of the function to a value can be described by a root type (a right inverse), in the same way that quotient types and subtractive types have meaning in type theory literature as related to product types and sum types.

Comment: My conjecture is that the "root" describes the cardinality of function application in the same way that an "exponential" describes the cardinality of functions.

Comment: I recognize that cardinality is usually described discretely, here I'm treating it as a real number that can describe operations on discrete units.

Answer (score 0):

This is the definition of root and logarithms.

And the usual notation for the inverse of a function $f$ is $f^{-1}$, which satisfies $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ and $f(f^{-1}(y))=y$

$\log_a(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ where $f(x)=a^x$

$\sqrt x=f^{-1}(x)$ where $f(x)=x^a$.

Function composition, which is denoted by $h=f\circ g$, creates a new function $h$ which computes to be $h(x)=f(g(x))$. So the inverses, can also be defines as $f\circ f^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ f=Id$ where $Id$ is the identity function which gets an input $x$ and returns it unchanged.

Comment: Thank you for this response! You've defined two functions f that compute an exponentiation, but I'm not sure this quite fits the idea of function types themselves as exponents: ie the function space Maybe[Bool] -> Bool has cardinality represented by the exponentiation of Bool ^ Maybe[Bool] such that 2^3 such possible functions exist. I'm interpreting your answer slightly differently.

Comment: I don't quite get how this relates to booleans. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Boolean is an example datatype - it has two inhabitants (true, false). Maybe[Bool] has three inhabitants (none, some(true), some(false)). Thus, the number of possible functions with the type Maybe[Bool] -> Bool is 2^3 or 8, representable by the table [[F F F] [F F T] [F T F] [F T T] [T F F] [T F T] [T T F] [T T T]] where each entry represents the Bool output for each possible Maybe[Bool] input.